# EntityFramework, DbContextScope and Effort - exception: DbContext has been disposed inside unit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dbcontext, effort

I am trying to write unit tests (with NUnit) for service layer which uses:

1. Entity Framework as Data Access Layer
2. [DbContextScope](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) for managing DbContext lifetime

I also use [Effort.EF6](https://effort.codeplex.com/) for mocking DbContext in unit tests. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to make DbContextScope compatibile with Effort so that I can correctly test all cases.

---

**Overview of the code**

Service layer consists of classes (services) which do some business logic. Each method is treated as a complete transaction, ended with `context.SaveChanges()`. Example:

```
    private IDbContextScopeFactory _dbContextScopeFactory;

    public DepartmentsService(IDbContextScopeFactory dbContextScopeFactory)
    {
        _dbContextScopeFactory = dbContextScopeFactory;
    }

    public BusinessModel.Department Insert(BusinessModel.Department department)
    {
        using (var dbContextScope = _dbContextScopeFactory.Create())
        {
            // Validation
            ValidateAndThrowOnFailure(department, new DepartmentAddValidator());

            // Operation
            DBModel.Department newDepartment = Mapper.Map<DBModel.Department>(department);

            newDepartment.InsertDateUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;

            dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<DPSContext>().Departments.Add(newDepartment);
            dbContextScope.SaveChanges();

            return Mapper.Map<BusinessModel.Department>(newDepartment);
        }
    }
```

To unit test such method, I do some preparation before each test:

```
    private IDepartmentsService _departmentsService;
    private IDbContextScopeFactory _dbContextScopeFactory;
    private IDbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
    private DBModel.DPSContext _dbEntities;

    [SetUp]
    public void ReInitializeTest()
    {
        // Setup DbContext with Effort.EF6
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DPSContext"].ConnectionString;
        DbConnection connection = EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(connStr);
        _dbEntities = new DBModel.DPSContext(connection);

        // Fill DbContext with in-memory data
        _dbEntities.Departments.AddRange(DataInitializer.GetDepartments());
        _dbEntities.SaveChanges();

        // Mock IDbContextFactory so that it returns in-memory context
        var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory>();

        contextFactoryMock
            .Setup(f => f.CreateDbContext<DBModel.DPSContext>())
            .Returns(_dbEntities);

        _dbContextFactory = contextFactoryMock.Object;

        // Setup DbContextScopeFactory to use mocked context
        _dbContextScopeFactory = new DbContextScopeFactory(_dbContextFactory);
        _departmentsService = new DepartmentsService(_dbContextScopeFactory);
    }
```

---

**The test and the problem**

Here is a simple unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Insert_WhenValidModelPassed_ShouldInsertNewRecord()
    {
        // Given
        BusinessModel.Department newDepartment = DataInitializer.GetExampleOfNewDepartment();

        // When
        _departmentsService.Insert(newDepartment);

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(3, _dbEntities.Departments.Count());
    }
```

The problem is that the test fails with exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

It seems that DbContextScope used inside `Insert` method internally disposes assigned contexts at the end of the `using` block and thus the `Assert` throws exception when invoked. Has anybody come across a similar problem or just knows what I should do to successfuly test this and similar scenarios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone who comes across a similar issue, I've created a bit dirty-but-working solution (at least I hope so). In addition to what I wrote in the question, I created a class derived from real context and made `Dispose` method do... nothing. I also added a `RealDispose` method which is called at the end of each test.

```
    public class TestableDPSContext : DBModel.DPSContext
    {
        public TestableDPSContext(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection)
        {

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        public void RealDispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Invoke real dispose
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void FinishTest()
    {
        _dbEntities.RealDispose(false);
    }
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but for now it seems to resolve the problem with `DbContext` being disposed too early in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "XUnit + NSubstitute + EF Core" version of the very useful PJDev answer:

```
public class TestableAppDbContext: AppDbContext
{
    public TestableAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public override ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        // Do nothing
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void RealDispose()
    {
        // Invoke real dispose
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public ValueTask RealDisposeAsync()
    {
        // Invoke real dispose
        return base.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

public abstract class UnitTestCollectionBase: IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    protected AppDbContext? Db { get; private set; }

    protected IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> BuildInMemoryDatabaseDbContextFactory(
        Action<AppDbContext>? seeding = null)
    {
        var dbContextFactory = Substitute.For<IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>>();
        Db = MakeAppDbContextInMemory();
        if (seeding is not null)
        {
            seeding(Db);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext().Returns(Db);
        dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync().ReturnsForAnyArgs(Task.FromResult(Db));
        return dbContextFactory;
    }
    
    private static TestableAppDbContext MakeAppDbContextInMemory()
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyApp");

        var appDbContext = new TestableAppDbContext(builder.Options);

        return appDbContext;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ((TestableAppDbContext?)Db)?.RealDispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (Db is not null)
            await ((TestableAppDbContext)Db).RealDisposeAsync();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I make a special `IDbContextFactory`. It always returns the single `TestableAppDbContext` used during the test. But each test has its own `IDbContextFactory` and own `TestableAppDbContext`.